# How to specify sections in main template of Ember application

Tags: javascript, templates, ember.js, handlebars.js

Is there a possibility to specify named sections in Ember application main template (application.hbs) and then to override them in route templates? I.e., to make something like this:

**application.hbs**

```
...
<div id="main-content">{{outlet}}</div>
<div id="bottom-panel">{{yield "bottom-panel"}}</div>
...
```

and then, in the route template override {{yield "bottom-panel"}} content.

Comment: can you be more specific on what you are trying to accomplish?  You can conditionally display blocks in `application.hbs` and you can also use named `{{yield}}`s in parent components which you can 'override' in child components.

Comment: @ctcpip, thank you very much for your comment. It helped me very much. Named yield was exactly the thing I was looking for. Named section is the same thing, but from Razor template engine.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Not with ember itself yet. There are some addons for this, for example [`ember-block-slots`](https://github.com/ciena-blueplanet/ember-block-slots).

However there [is an RFC for this](https://github.com/emberjs/rfcs/blob/master/text/0226-named-blocks.md), so it will be part of ember in the future.

Also interesting might be [`ember-wormhole`](https://github.com/yapplabs/ember-wormhole), or [`ember-elsewhere`](https://github.com/ef4/ember-elsewhere).

Here its interesting to look in which direction you want to blocks to flow. If you want to put stuff elsewhere in a parent component look at `ember-wormhole` or `ember-elsewhere`. If you want a component to specify multiple places where the parent can place content, then `ember-block-slots` is the right choice. Also if you have these *things* you want to put into places in a child component are components, you can do it with plain ember:

```
{{#my-component footer=(component 'my-super-footer')}}
  Main stuff
{{/my-component}}
```

and then do this inside `my-component`:

```
<div class="main">
  {{yield}}
<div>
<div class="footer">
  {{component footer}}
</div>
```

Comment: Thank you very much for such a detailed answer!!! I've ended up with ember-block-slots add-on, because I needed a component to specify multiple places where the parent can place content. Also I found  another possible solution for such case [here](https://spin.atomicobject.com/2016/05/03/reusable-page-layouts-ember/).  And I even didn't imagine that I can pass a component to a component. :)